# Implement Stripe Payment Gateway using ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, payment-gateway, stripe-payments

How to implement and integrate "Stripe" on-line payment gateway using ASP.NET and C#? When I go through their on-line documentation, then found only 4 ways to implement the same i.e.

1. RUBY
2. PYTHON
3. PHP
4. NODE.JS

I have no experience implementation NODE.JS with ASP.NET and C#. If possible, help me out on how to integrate STRIPE using ASP.NET and C#.

I know there are 3 libraries present on GitHub for C# to implement Stripe Payment Gateway i.e.

1. XamarinStripe by the people at Xamarin.
2. Stripe.NET by Jayme Davis.
3. ServiceStack.Stripe by TeamServiceStack

But they are not very well explained in the Readme File on GitHub, that is why seek guidance  in a proper way to implement the same.

Comment: Have you looked at their [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs)??

Comment: A small googling can give you proper library http://cmatskas.com/processing-payments-on-your-site-using-stripe-and-net/

Comment: [Click here before you post your next question.](http://s.tk/onhold)

Comment: I know there are 3 libraries present on GitHub for C# to implement Stripe Payment Gateway. But they are not very well explained in the Readme File on GitHub, that is why seek guidance in a proper way to implement the same.

Comment: Stripe Payment Integration in Asp.net Web Forms and its 100 percent  working code and you can also download application 
https://code2night.com/Blog/MyBlog/Implement-Stripe-Payment-Gateway-In-ASPNET

Answer (score 2):

There is a .net library for Stripe. Have a look at following link
https://github.com/jaymedavis/stripe.net

Comment: I have tried bit not helped me up

Comment: I had also tried. But this code not working properly.if you have another code.please share .

Comment: Stripe Payment Integration in Asp.net Web Forms and its 100 percent  working code and you can also download application 
https://code2night.com/Blog/MyBlog/Implement-Stripe-Payment-Gateway-In-ASPNET